# Undefined symbol in so (defined in linked object)

Tags: c++, linker, development-environment

I have a problem with shared library that I build. It is based on wpa_cli and use wpa_ctrl.
Symbols from wpa_ctrl are included, but from eloop - not:

```
g++ -Wall -g -fPIC -DPIC -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -pthread -g -fno-exceptions -pthread -DPIC -fPIC -shared libwlan.o  wpa_supplicant-2.2/src/common/wpa_ctrl.o wpa_supplicant-2.2/src/utils/eloop.o wpa_supplicant-2.2/src/utils/wpa_debug.o wpa_supplicant-2.2/src/utils/common.o wpa_supplicant-2.2/src/utils/os_unix.o wpa_supplicant-2.2/src/utils/edit_simple.o -o libwlan.so
```

.

```
nm wpa_supplicant-2.2/src/common/wpa_ctrl.o | grep wpa_ctrl_attach
00000578 T wpa_ctrl_attach
nm libs/libwlan/libwlan.so | grep wpa_ctrl_attach
00040340 T wpa_ctrl_attach
```

.

```
nm wpa_supplicant-2.2/src/utils/eloop.o | grep eloop_register_read_sock 
000003bc T eloop_register_read_sock
nm libs/libwlan/libwlan.so | grep eloop_register_read_sock
000407dc T eloop_register_read_sock
         U _Z24eloop_register_read_sockiPFviPvS_ES_S_
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to expose the function in an unmangled form - it should look like `eloop_register_read_sock`, and not `_Z24eloop_register_read_sockiPFviPvS_ES_S_`.

the `eloop.h` code does not have c++ name demangling guards, so in your C++ code where you perform:

```
#include <eloop.h>
```

you need to do:

```
extern "C" {
#include <eloop.h>
}
```

This should prevent you from ending up with the mangled form of the routine.

The wpa_supplicant library is a `C` based library, and so if you're planning on introducing `C++` code you will have to use `extern "C"` on points where the `C++` code interacts with the routines exposed in the `.h.` files.